# Is it possible to boot a PC with a USB video adapter only?

Tags: windows, graphics-card

i.e. when the PC doesn't have a PCIe or built-in video, only an external USB video, and OS is already installed. Is it possible?

Comment: *"when the PC doesn't have a PCIe or built-in video"* - It is relatively common for systems to have integrated graphics, whether on the chipsets or more recently the CPU. Please consider [edit]ing your question to include the hardware you are referring that doesn't have this.

Comment: @Anaksunaman there are lots of CPUs that don' have any built-in graphics, for instance most Ryzen CPUs. But if you're trying to answer this question, you should know that already.

Comment: Is video adapter crucial to booting anyway

Comment: @TomYan no idea.

Comment: @user626528 It depends on the motherboard. My MSI s1151v1 Intel board does not boot without GPU and HDMI dongle, my ASRock AM4 board boots without GPU. It would be nice to boot the MSI board with an USB GPU, because of the extra PCIE slot I could free this way. I have no idea whether this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible according to Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/9uihlb/comment/e94v6xj/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

> You're not going to find a USB to VGA adapter that will work in BIOS.
> The BIOS doesn't know how to initialize and use it, and there's no way
> to make it able to.

https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/v7bben/comment/ibk10bt/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

> Troubleshooting/setup sometimes involves messing with the BIOS
> settings and/or editing the kernel command line in GRUB. Both of these
> tasks rely on the platform firmware (BIOS/UEFI) to be able to output
> video through the display adapter, which is possible only via PCIe,
> because PCIe display adapters contain a ROM which contains the driver
> which is used by the BIOS.
>
> For USB 2.0 DisplayLink display adapters, they only start working if
> the OS loads the driver.

Though some motherboards are capable to boot without video card, so try that first.